# gradle generates xml from job-dsl-plugin

Tags: gradle, jenkins-job-dsl

Has anyone setup a gradle build to generate Jobs DSL xml locally?

- Run a DSL Script on a local system (see [User-Power-Moves](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/docs/User-Power-Moves.md))
- Adding to gradle (see [IDE-support](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/b3bd3488f6c7389be8df0c7e473d0144c364a6ad/docs/IDE-Support.md))

So I added a sourceSet for jobs and the plugin dependency.  So I can build the groovy into classes.  Now I think I want to add an execution task that I link to compile or maybe test that generates in a gradle equivalent to the following but I'm not quite sure of the best way to do this.

I have access to the jar already via classpath (in theory) so I should be able to exec easily

```
curl -O https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/job-dsl-core/@version@/job-dsl-core-@version@-standalone.jar
java -jar job-dsl-core-@version@-standalone.jar sample.dsl.groovy
```

## build.gradle

```
sourceSets {
...
    jobs {
        groovy {
            srcDirs 'jenkins-job-dsl'
            compileClasspath += main.compileClasspath
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
...
compile "org.jenkins-ci.plugins:job-dsl-core:$version"
}

task buildOneUsingClassFile(type: JavaExec) {
    group = "Execution"
    classpath = sourceSets.jobs.runtimeClasspath + sourceSets.jobs.compileClasspath
    main = 'my_pipeline_dsl_job_class_name'
}

task generateDSLXml(type: JavaExec) {
    group = "Execution"
    description = "generate all found groovy dsl files"
    classpath = sourceSets.jobs.compileClasspath
    main = 'javaposse.jobdsl.Run'
    args sourceSets.jobs.groovy
      .filter { it.path.endsWith('.groovy') }
      .collect {it.path.toString() }
      .unique()
}
```

The above mostly works, except that I see failures that work on jenkins itself even with the same version.  However, I see those same failures on https://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/ too so they may represent a different issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Gradle

- Add source set for job-dsl files
- Add output dir for job-dsl ext.jobDslOutputDir
- Add dependencies for job-dsl
- Add task for job-dsl

```
buildscript {
    ...
    ext {
    ...
        jobDslOutputDir = new File(buildDir, 'generated/jenkins-job-dsl')
    }

}

sourceSets {
    // our shared library internal code
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['resources']
        }
    }
    // out shared library test code
    test {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['test']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['resources']
        }
    }
    // job DSL files
    jobs {
        groovy {
            srcDirs 'jenkins-job-dsl'
            compileClasspath += main.compileClasspath
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-multibranch:2.24@jar'
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins:job-dsl-core:1.77'
}


// Generate Task
task generateDSLXml(type: JavaExec) {
    doFirst {
        // ensure Project's ext.jobDslOutputDir directory exists
        jobDslOutputDir.mkdirs()
    }

    group = "Execution"
    description = "generate job xml for all found groovy dsl files"
    classpath = sourceSets.jobs.compileClasspath
    main = 'javaposse.jobdsl.Run'
    workingDir = jobDslOutputDir
    // collect all the groovy files found in the jobs source set for they represent
    // the job dsl files creating jobs
    args sourceSets.jobs.groovy.filter { it.path.endsWith('.groovy') }.collect { it.path.toString() }.unique()
}

// disable spotbugs for job DSL
task spotbugs(
        group: "Verification",
        description: """Marker task to enable Spotbugs (disabled by default)."""
)
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    tasks.spotbugsMain.onlyIf { taskGraph.hasTask tasks.spotbugs }
    tasks.spotbugsTest.onlyIf { taskGraph.hasTask tasks.spotbugs }
    tasks.spotbugsJobs.onlyIf { false } // skip for job dsl
}
```

## Job DSL multi branch and missing method problems

For multi branch we should be able to use

```
multibranchPipelineJob('my-build') {
    factory {
        workflowBranchProjectFactory {
            scriptPath('path-to-Jenkinsfile')
        }
    }
}
```

However this fails with a missing method error.  When we refactor thus found [here](https://gist.github.com/jondkelley/fc7812158d98003ea504365a6195d59a), generation works on [dsl playground](https://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/) and via gradle

```
        it / factory(class: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowBranchProjectFactory') {
            owner(class: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject', reference: '../..')
            scriptPath("jenkinsfile")
        }
    }
```